# Laravel intended always returns email/verify

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel 7.4, and I want to redirect the users to the page they came from after the login. I edited the file RedirectIfAuthenticated and added the redirect like:

```
return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
```

But the problem is, it always redirected me to home. When I actually logged what the intended function returns, it always returns the url as website.com/email/verify. I'm 100% sure I don't redirect the users to that url, because I am logging in with an already verified user.

It might be some FW setup that I failed to notice, since I took over this project from another developer. I'll provide any more info if needed.

Comment: You misunderstand the point of this middleware.  Its only purpose is to deflect users away from the guest pages when they are logged in.  It does not play any part in deciding where the user goes after login

Comment: looks like you are also redirecting users that have not verified their account, which will take precedence over all else

Answer (score 2):

Check for middleware maybe you are redirecting unverified users to email/verify

Then in your `LoginController` create a `protected function redirectTo()` and return url()->previous();

Your code will look like this

```
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return url()->previous();
    }
```

Or
Also you can add `$this->redirectTo = url()->previous()` to your constructor
like this

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->redirectTo = url()->previous();
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you dump `dd(session()->all())` of a so-called "intended" page, you will see the following:

[image]

As you can see, Laravel store user's previously intended page at `url['intended']` array element. So to imitate this behavior manually, you have to set this value manually where needed. In this case it's `LoginController`:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    session()->put('url.intended', url()->previous());
    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
```

Now the original location has been stored, and later when the user log in, they will be redirected as declared in `RedirectIfAuthenticated@handle`:

```
return redirect()->intended(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
```

But what if the user went to the `/login` page intentionally, or simply put, what if they refresh the page? `url.intended` will have the value of `route('login')`, then when user logged in, they will be redirected to login page and the infinite loop continues.

In that case, `url.intended` should not have any value. `RouteServiceProvider::HOME` value will be used as destination. There must be additional condition for that, let's say your site have login route named `login`:

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    if (($url()->previous() != route('login')) {
        session()->put('url.intended', url()->previous());
    }        
    return view('admin.auth.login');
}
```

Case anything unclear, you may want to [have a look at similar question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/manually-set-intended-url-for-login)